# Excluir de consulta condiciones anidadas SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Hola por favor me ayudan con el siguiente resultado esperado en SQL Server:

Tabla mantenciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito excluir las siguientes condiciones :

id = 1 AND repuesto = ruedas

id = 2 AND repuesto = bateria

Resultado esperado :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Desde ya agradeceré cualquier ayuda o guía, gracias.

```
create table #mantenciones (id nvarchar(12), marca nvarchar(40), repuesto nvarchar(40), fecha date) 
insert into #mantenciones values ('1','chevrolet','motor','2017-01-15')
insert into #mantenciones values ('1','chevrolet','ruedas','2020-07-02')
insert into #mantenciones values ('1','chevrolet','bateria','2020-10-02')
insert into #mantenciones values ('2','toyota','motor','2016-02-20')
insert into #mantenciones values ('2','toyota','ruedas','2020-01-01')
insert into #mantenciones values ('2','toyota','bateria','2021-01-02')
insert into #mantenciones values ('3','fiat','motor','2017-02-20')
insert into #mantenciones values ('3','fiat','ruedas','2026-01-01')
insert into #mantenciones values ('3','fiat','bateria','2020-01-02')

SELECT * FROM #mantenciones order by id, marca, repuesto asc
drop table #mantenciones
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existen muchas formas de realizar lo que pides.

Una puede ser utilizar el operador [except](https://javifer2.wordpress.com/2020/04/10/except/).

```
-- Opcion except
SELECT * FROM #mantenciones 
except 
select * from #mantenciones
where
(id = 1 AND repuesto = 'ruedas')
or
(id = 2 AND repuesto = 'bateria')
```

De manera que obtienes todos los registros de la tabla a excepción de los registros que no quieres que obtienes en el segundo conjunto.

Otra opción puede ser utilizar [Not](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/language-elements/not-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Niegas todo lo que te resolvería la consulta encerrándolo entre paréntesis

```
-- Opción not
select * from #mantenciones
where
not((id = 1 AND repuesto = 'ruedas')
    or
    (id = 2 AND repuesto = 'bateria'))

order by id, marca, repuesto asc
```

[image: Resultados]

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier, utilice la segunda opción "NOT" y funciona perfecto. La primera igual funcionaba pero se producian unos segundos de diferencia en la ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta concatenar los id con el repuesto:

```
create table #mantenciones (id nvarchar(12), marca nvarchar(40), repuesto nvarchar(40), fecha date) 
insert into #mantenciones values ('1','chevrolet','motor','2017-01-15')
insert into #mantenciones values ('1','chevrolet','ruedas','2020-07-02')
insert into #mantenciones values ('1','chevrolet','bateria','2020-10-02')
insert into #mantenciones values ('2','toyota','motor','2016-02-20')
insert into #mantenciones values ('2','toyota','ruedas','2020-01-01')
insert into #mantenciones values ('2','toyota','bateria','2021-01-02')
insert into #mantenciones values ('3','fiat','motor','2017-02-20')
insert into #mantenciones values ('3','fiat','ruedas','2026-01-01')
insert into #mantenciones values ('3','fiat','bateria','2020-01-02')

SELECT * FROM #mantenciones as m WHERE id + '-' + repuesto NOT IN('1-ruedas','2-bateria')

order by id, marca, repuesto asc
drop table #mantenciones
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias amigo por tu tiempo,

Comment: Interesante solucion

Answer (score 1):

```
select* from #mantenciones
where (id <> 1 and repuesto <> 'ruedas') or (id <> 2 and repuesto <> 'bateria')
order by id, marca, repuesto asc
```

Usas el **operador relacional <>** para expresar si un valor es **distinto de otro**, aquí por ejemplo, al decir:

```
where (id <> 1 and repuesto <> 'ruedas')
```

Estás filtrando solamente los valores cuyo **id** es **distinto** de **1** y cuyo **campo repuesto** es **distinto** de **'ruedas'**, en otras palabras o dicho al revés, descartas los valores cuyo **id** es **1** y el **campo repuesto** es **'ruedas'**.

Comment: Gracias Japv, esto es una opción valida tambien.